# getting the referral url of the link in google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a google chrome extension which will hav a pop-up, and which will display me the referral of the link in the tab when the favicon is pressed
below is my code. But its not working. Please let me know were i am doing it wrong

this is my manifes.json:

```
{
"name": "Tab History",
"version": "1.0",
"description" : "simple sweet" , 
"permissions": ["tabs","history", ],
"manifest_version": 2 , 

"browser_action": {
"default_popup": "main.html" },
"background": {
"scripts": ["graph.js"], "persistent": false
              },
"content_scripts" : [
{
"matches" : ["<all_urls>"] ,
"js" : ["contentscript.js"] ,
"page" : "main.html"
}
]}
```

this is my main.html

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  body {min-width: 300px;}
</style>
<script src='graph.js'></script>  
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map">     
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my contentscript.js

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({ref: document.referrer}) ;
```

this is graph.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var arr = new Array();
getmylist("map");});



function getmylist(divName, arr)
{   
 /*
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true},function(tabs) { 
 var d = tabs[0].id; 
 document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML =  d;
});
  */


 chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
 var referrer = request.ref;
 document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML = referrer ; 

 }

 }
```

Comment: You keep quite about the error message you got. Where can you see error messages? The errors concerned the background of your extension is displayed: extenions >> your extension >> inspect views background.html >> Console tab on the new window. The errors taken place in a particular tab is displayed: Open Developer tools (press F12) >> console tab. I hope after reading the error message you forget the obsolete onRequest and you find the proper method for message passing.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion it helped me to correct some errors and also to change obsolete sendRequest and onRequest to sendMessage and onMessage. But its still not working. Stil it shows no result. Am I doing it in right way to abstract referral of link in extension?

Comment: Can you update your source codes?

Comment: I had edited the code.. this doesn't show any error on console

Answer (score 0):

My post is too long as a comment, so I post here: First of all I recommend you rename graph.js to background.js and main.html to popup.html. In your manifest file in the content_scripts there is a "page" item which does not exist -- check the documentation -- so delete that. Secondly for debug purpose log the document and document.referrer both in the content script and in the background. You will see that in the content script it works fine but in the background page you get an error. Although you didn't declare background.html, it will be automatically created. You can check this background page: chrome >> extension >> your extension >> inspect views: background >> Elements. When you refer in background.js to 'document' than you refer to this html indeed and not the popup.html at all. That is why your solution can't work and you must get an error on the >> inspect views: background >> console. Check it! Here is the logic you should implement: you should send a message from the popup script (it is a new file) that will be caught by a content script listener and the content script listener send back the referrer.

Comment: Thanks for your response, actually this comment let me to clear lot of my concepts.